# Drools: Access rules stored in Guvnor in Java web app

Tags: loading, rules, drools

Our Business analyst loads rules in Guvnor. How do I access/load that in code in my Java web app ? They want to be able to change the rules independent of the Java web app.

I have seen code similar to this but I am not sure.

```
kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(new StringInputStream(myDrlAsString)), ResourceType.DRL);

kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(myDrlAsByteArr)), ResourceType.DRL);
```

Do I have to store the Guvnor rules in some classpath outside the web-app that can then be loaded by the java webapp ?

TIA,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer.
java.io.FileInputStream fis =null;
fis = new java.io.FileInputStream
           (new java.io.File( ASSET_FILES[0] ) );

```
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(fis), ResourceType.DRL);
```